# Gas price sending ether

Tags: ether

Do I have to pay a gas price if I send ether from account a to account b in Ethereum MainNet?? Or the transaction is free of cost?'

And if I buy ether from [Changelly](https://changelly.com) the destination address have to pay something extra?? Or I get the "clean" quantity of the value that I buy in the addres. For example , If I buy 50€ in ether are going to receive 0.26670439eth??

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic minimum price for a transaction is 21000 gas. If you send Ethers anywhere that is the amount of gas you have to pay.

But the actual amount of Ethers you need to spend for the transaction depends on the gas price. So you implicitly "buy" the gas with the given gas price. So you will eventually pay `gas price * gas amount = X Ethers` for your transaction.

So, yes, you have to pay for any transaction.

There are no free transactions - only calls to `view` or `pure` functions are free as they do not go to the blockchain.

The receiver of Ether never pays anything, it's the sender who always pays. But I cannot comment on what amount of Ether you'd get from Changelly - check their own documentation.

Comment: Thankyou for the anser I understand. I update the question in this new scenario. (The question edit) the mount that I receive is take it out the transaction fee I sopouse, or Im wrong??

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly